# how to express the following SQL in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, subquery

How to express the following SQL in HQL.

```
select *  from (
            select *
            from vw_report_alert r 
            where r.user_id=147  
            order by r.event_creation_date DESC
           ) 
     where rownum <= 25
     order by alert_id DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible to do it directly. But there's a simple workaround:

```
String hql = "select r from VwReportAlert r where r.user.id = 147"
             + " order by r.eventCreationDate desc";
List<VwReportAlert> result = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(25).list();
Collections.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder(new ByAlertIdComparator()));
return result;
```

Sure, the list is sorted in Java, but the sort is easy, and the list size is very small.

Comment: Thanks JB,In my case I would have to do sorting in DB, my client has specific sorting requirements. I now start thinking, may be it is possible to move subquery in where clause, and may be use Criteria api instead.

Comment: Everything that can be done in Criteria can also be done with HQL. The inverse is not true. So you'll be more limited with Criteria than with HQL. But I don't see why these specific sorting requirements couldn't be satisfied with Java.

Comment: Sure they could be, it is just I want to keep sorting specifics in one place.  For now, since I don't have much time, I have created 2 queries those are trivial. I can post it here if any body wants. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ROWNUM` is vendor-specific functionality (Oracle, specifically).  SQLServer has something very similar when creating queries using pseudo-limits: queries have to be wrapped in `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...` which isn't something you can normally do in Hibernate without resorting to raw SQL.

What I would recommend doing is checking the [vendor-specific dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) you're using for support of this functionality.  They have one for all the major vendors, including:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- Oracle
- SQLServer
- Sybase
- etc.

Also make sure you're actually using the correct dialect in your hibernate configuration.

From perusing the source, it appears Hibernate has supported Oracle's `ROWNUM` function since at least Oracle 8.

EDIT:
This should produce what you're looking for. I took the liberty of converting DB fields/tables to Java-appropriate names because it looks like you're using raw SQL instead of Java objects (table "vw_report_alert" -> VwReportAlert, column "user_id" -> userId, column "alert_id" -> id, column "event_creation_date" -> eventCreationDate)

```
getSession().createQuery(
  "select r from VwReportAlert r " +
  "where r.userId = :userId " +
  "order by r.eventCreationDate desc, r.id desc")
.setInteger("userId", 147)
.setMaxResults(25)
.list();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am using Oracle and correct Dialect, I don't have issue with rownum in other cases, I am just not used to sub queries.

Comment: Matt, if you read original SQL more carefully, you will see that first it gets all reports for user sorted by creation date, then takes 25 records from that sorted collection and sorts those 25 records by alert id. In your case it will apply double sort and then get 25 records, this unfortunately not what the client wants.

Comment: A sort on date, trimmed to 25, then sort on ID assumes the natural sort order will be respected. I do not assume any such thing, which is why I specify the ID in the sort.If there are 1000 records that all match on the date, you have no way of guaranteeing which 25 records of the 1000 you're going to get.  My "date, id" enforces repeatable results.